VideoReader on torchvision on Kaggle outputs AttributeError: 'av.audio.codeccontext.AudioCodecContext' object has no attribute 'average_rate'
I'm simply trying to read a video with torchvision's VideoReader on a Kaggle notebook.
Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

I thought it might be related with the libs versions, so I set them to the last one:
!pip install torch=='2.3.0'
!pip install pyav=='12.0.5'
!pip install av=='12.0.0'
!pip install torchvision=='0.18'
!pip install torchaudio=='2.3.0'

Which caused no effect.
My code is as simple as:
import torch
import torchvision 

video_path = os.path.join(VIDEOS, '001', '001_segment_1.mp4')

video = torchvision.io.VideoReader(video_path, 'video')
video.get_metadata()


Interestingly, the line where the failure occurs appears to be attempting to check whether that attribute is available so that it can use another if it isn't, but the check throws the error anyway. This could be a compatibility issue with python versions? Would that check succeed in some versions of python, but not the one used on Kaggle (or Colab, where I'm seeing it)?

The average_rate property appears to have been removed from PyAV's Stream class some time between version 11.0.0 and 12.0.0, and is now only available on actual video streams but not audio streams.  I'd suggest using pip install av==11.0.0 and seeing if that works; it seems to be good on Colab, so presume it will also work on Kaggle.
